# How to connect to mongodb with python

Tags: python, mongodb

I tried connecting my application to my cluster on mongodb Atlas [like the examples](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/#driver-examples) but I'm still having trouble.

I used

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb+srv://kay:myrealpassword@cluster0.mongodb.net/test')
```

I replaced myrealpassword with my password and cluster0 with my cluster's name .

This is the error i got :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 468,
>   in **init**
>       res = uri_parser.parse_uri(entity, port, warn=True)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 399,
>   in parse_uri
>       nodes = _get_dns_srv_hosts(fqdn)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py", line 289,
>   in _get_dns_srv_hosts
>       raise ConfigurationError(str(exc)) pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: None of DNS query names exist:
>   _mongodb._tcp.saudimood.mongodb.net., _mongodb._tcp.saudimood.mongodb.net.Home.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar DNS error, I misspelled the [DNS seed list](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/index.html#dns-seed-list-connection-format) :s

To avoid this and another errors try:

1. In the **Clusters** view, click **Connect** for the cluster to which you
   want to connect.
2. Select **Connect your application**.
3. Select your driver and version.
4. Copy the connection string.
5. Replace `<password>` with the password for the `<username>` user. Replace `myFirstDatabase` with the name of the database that connections will use by default.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Try it

```
pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://user:password@servername/dbname')
```

Comment: This does not address the dns issue

Comment: this does not answer the question.